# file_put_contents(path): failed to open stream: Is a directory

Tags: php, laravel

#### Environment:

- Laravel Version: 5.8.29
- PHP Version `$ php --version`: PHP 7.2.24 (cli)

---

#### Problem Statement:

I'm unable to download file from **s3** to **local** disk using [`put`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances) method in created directory.

> ErrorException (E_WARNING) : file_put_contents(/path/storage/4804_1626): failed to open stream: Is a directory

However, I've found that directory has been created with below permission. I tried setting permission `777` as passing third parameter in [`makeDirectory()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#directories) method but it didn't work.

```
ubuntu@ip:~/path/storage$ ll
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4096 Sep 20 07:07  4804_1626/
```

---

##### Files & Configuration:

```
$folderPath = Storage::disk('local')->makeDirectory($folderName, 0777);

$contents = Storage::disk('s3')->get('path/' . $fileName);

Storage::disk('local')->put($folderName, $contents); // Following line is throwing error
```

---

Comment: you are putting the file in a folder itself. try after foldername /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify full path to file, not only folder:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put($folderName . '/' . $fileName, $contents);
```